# How to install ECK on GKE, with 2 environment (production and development)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I follow instructions from : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/1.0/k8s-quickstart.html#k8s-deploy-elasticsearch. But I am wondering how to differentiate the installation between ECK for production and ECK for development.

1. Should I install Elasticsearch operator for production and development respectively?
2. What is relation between elastic operator and elastic node? And how do I know which elastic operator manages a node in development environment?

Comment: How exactly have you set up your prod and dev environments on GKE? In general, [ECK operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-installing-eck.html)  can be installed to be restricted to a pre-defined set of namespaces - in particular, when namespaces are used to isolate different environments on the same GKE cluster.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it:

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=default
kubectl create -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.4.0/crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.4.0/operator.yaml
```

production deployment:

```
kubectl apply -f prod-depl.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: production
  labels:
    name: production
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-prod
  namespace: production
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-prod
  namespace: production
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: data-es
  namespace: production
spec:
  version: 8.4.3
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
      podTemplate:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: elasticsearch
              # resources:
              #   limits:
              #     memory: 2Gi
              #     cpu: 2
              # env:
              #   - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              #     value: "-Xms2g -Xmx4g"
              volumeMounts:
                - name: elasticsearch-data-prod
                  mountPath: /usr/share/production/elasticsearch/data
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: elasticsearch-data-prod
          spec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            storageClassName: standard
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi

---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: data-kibana
  namespace: production
spec:
  version: 8.4.3
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: data-es
```

dev deployment:

```
kubectl apply -f dev-depl.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: development
  labels:
    name: development
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-dev
  namespace: development
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-dev
  namespace: development
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: data-es
  namespace: development
spec:
  version: 8.4.3
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
      podTemplate:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: elasticsearch
              # resources:
              #   limits:
              #     memory: 2Gi
              #     cpu: 2
              # env:
              #   - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              #     value: "-Xms2g -Xmx4g"
              volumeMounts:
                - name: elasticsearch-data-dev
                  mountPath: /usr/share/development/elasticsearch/data
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: elasticsearch-data-dev
          spec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            storageClassName: standard
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 1Gi

---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: data-kibana
  namespace: development
spec:
  version: 8.4.3
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: data-es
```